# save data from API response to using it app script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm using app script to get data from API to put it to google sheet. I'm using one API Endpoint to get many information, Example of response: `{"name": "john", "age": "24", "gender": "male", "price": "10",} .`

This is my code to get every value :

```
function getName() {

       var url = "*****************";
       var apiRequest = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
       var jsonResponce = JSON.parse(apiRequest);
       var name= jsonResponce.name;
       return name;
  }
```

I add this function in cell like that `getName()` and return me the value.

So I do this way in the 4 value : name & age & gender & price, by one API and multi function like above `getName()` & `getAge()` & `getGender()` & `getPrice()` . every function put in another cell to get value.

this way called API 4 time in same time. I want to call this API response one time and return data and stored data : then I need to give the every value from this data, without calling API 4 time. calling one time in the first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call it once and save it to a global variable `apiResponse`. Use a function to return the desired values from the apiResponse:

```
var url = "*****************";
var apiRequest = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
var apiResponse = JSON.parse(apiRequest);

function getValue(key) {
  return apiResponse[key]
}
```

Now in your google sheet just add `=getValue("name")` in the cell to get the name.

Comment: This method call API every function using like : `=getValue("name")` OR `=getValue("age")` ..... I mean need to store it to another place not in sheet, and after run `=getValue("name")` OR  `=getValue("age")` don't call API.

Comment: And after run the main request API, the another function get value from main request API

Comment: That is exactly what it is doing. The API is only called once and the result is stored in a global variable. When you call getValue(), you only retrieve a value from the variable, you dont call the API again. But this is not the place to teach absolute fundamentals of programming in general. What I posted as an answer works, for the example you gave. I tested it with google sheets. If your data is more complex, e.g. an nested object, you need to do more. But that was not part of the question. Please check if it works and if there is no better answer, don't forget to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to retrieve the values of `name`, `age`, `gender`, and `price` by one API call and put them to the Spreadsheet.
- You want to achieve this using a custom function.

In this case, how about the following sample script? From your question, I understood that the returned value is `{"name": "john", "age": "24", "gender": "male", "price": "10",}`. In this case, the following script returns the values you want.

```js
function sample() {
  var jsonResponce = {"name": "john", "age": "24", "gender": "male", "price": "10"};
  const keys = ["name", "age", "gender", "price"]; // You can set the order of output values here.
  return [keys.map(k => jsonResponce[k])];
}
```

When the above script is reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Sample script:

```js
function sample() {
  var url = "*****************";
  var apiRequest = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var jsonResponce = JSON.parse(apiRequest.getContentText());
  const keys = ["name", "age", "gender", "price"]; // You can set the order of output values here.
  return [keys.map(k => jsonResponce[k])];
}
```

- When you put `=sample()` to a cell, each value is put to a row. When you want to put the values to a column, please modify `return [keys.map(k => jsonResponce[k])];` to `return keys.map(k => jsonResponce[k])`.

#### Note:

- When you don't use V8 runtime, please modify as follows.

  ```
    var keys = ["name", "age", "gender", "price"]; // You can set the order of output values here.
    return [keys.map(function(k) {return jsonResponce[k]})];
  ```

#### References:

- [Custom Functions in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

### Edit:

From the following replying,

> This method work if you need to put it horizontal or vertical without change any thing in this values. but some time I need to calculate some value by another value in another cell or add string in value like "&"name . the reason is to but run one function to get values From API and store it in same function this function running every minute or less, and then the another function get value from main function without run API.

I understood that you wanted to use the custom function like `=sample("name")` while you wanted to request the API by one call. Namely, you wanted to store the data from the API and wanted to use the data using the custom function.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

In this sample script, at first, the data is stored to PropertiesService by running the script of `storeData()`. And, when you put the custom function like `=sample("name")` to a cell, you can use the data retrieved from PropertiesService. In this case, the API request is only one time.

When you want to update the data, please run the function `storeData()`. By this, the data is updated. For example, when an image button is put to the Spreadsheet, you can also run the function by clicking the button.

```js
// Store the data to Properties service.
function storeData() {
  var url = "*****************";
  var apiRequest = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var jsonResponce = apiRequest.getContentText();
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty("data", jsonResponce);
  console.log("Stored at " + new Date());
}

// Custom function.
function sample(key) {
  var str = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty("data");
  var obj = JSON.parse(str);
  return obj[key] || "None"; 
}
```

#### Reference:

- [Properties Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties)

Comment: This method work if you need to put it horizontal or vertical without change any thing in this values. but some time I need to calculate some value by another value in another cell or add string in value like `"&"name `. the reason is to but run one function to get values From API and store it in same function this function running every minute or less, and then the another function get value from main function without run API.

Comment: @johnvan Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed one more sample script. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your goal, I apologize.